# Using .split in jquery and extracting the first item from array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a basic select field that display options with values that have a numeric value combined  with the a letter value such as `<option value=”36:a”>Hi</option>`. I am trying to extract just the numeric from the value. I worked mainly through php and used `explode` and then call the first item in the array `[0]` but not sure how to perform this in jquery/javascript. I am using split and then assigning pointing to the first item but that is not working. How can properly I extract just the numeric value from the option value?

```
var content = "<option value=\"36:Hi\">Hi</option>";
$(...).find(..).on('change', function(){ 
if($this.val().split(":")[0] == 36){    

}
});
```

Comment: it should be `if($(this).val().split(":")[0] == 36){ ` there is no `$this` defined in the change handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `parseInt()`, it takes a parameter with a number first (else it will yield `NaN`), and will parse until no number is found. So `parseInt("36:hi")` will log `36`

So:

```
if(parseInt($(this).val()) == 36)
```

Comment: Awesome! Was not aware of that.

Comment: I actually learned this today :D I was researching the difference between `Number()` and `parseInt()`

Comment: I will read more into that but Great! I avoid the hassle of having to split.

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
if($this.val().split(":")[0] == 36){
```

to

```
if($(this).val().split(":")[0] == 36){
```